# Minimum value of the function $\sin5x/\sin^5x$

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I recently came across a question as follows:

> Find the minimum value of the function $\sin5x/\sin^5x$.

I  tried differentiating the function but the calculation was messy. The resulting differentiated equation had many roots, difficult for me to identify which ones actually correspond to the minimum. Taking the second derivative  resulted in a horrendous calculation. Would someone please help me to find any easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $\dfrac{\sin (5x)}{\sin^5x}= \dfrac{16\sin^5x-20\sin^3x+5\sin x}{\sin^5x}= 16-\dfrac{20}{\sin^2x}+\dfrac{5}{\sin^4x}=16-20t+5t^2=f(t), t = \frac{1}{\sin^2x} \ge 1$. You can take it from here as you have a quadratic function in $t \ge 1$.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @Shashwat1337: I am glad to be able to help you. Thanks as well.

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

The derivative is

$$5\frac{\cos(5x)\sin(x)-\cos(x)\sin(5x)}{\sin^{10}(x)}\sin^4(x)$$

$$=\frac{-5\sin(4x)}{\sin^6(x)}$$

Your function is $2\pi-$periodic, even and satisfies
$$f(\pi-x)=f(x)$$
So, you just need to find the minimum at $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin 5x=\Re(e^{ix})^5=5\cos^4x\sin x-10\cos^2x\sin^3x+\sin^5x=16\sin^5x-20\sin^3x+5\sin x$$ and we want to maximize

$$16-20t^{-1}+5t^{-2}$$ over $[0,1]$, where $t:=\sin^2x$.

By canceling the derivative,

$$20t^{-2}-10t^{-3}$$ gives the root $t=\frac12$ and the minimum value

$$16-20\cdot2+5\cdot4=-4.$$

Comment: Your answer is also helpful. But unfortunately I can accept only one answer. Thanks.